# Set size on background image with CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to set the size of the background image with CSS?

I want to do something like:

```
background: url('bg.gif') top repeat-y;
background-size: 490px;
```

But it seems it's totally wrong to do it like that...

Comment: Maybe it's possible. See *[How To: Resizeable Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/)*.

Answer (score 629, accepted):

## CSS2

If you need to make the image bigger, you must edit the image itself in an image editor.

If you use the img tag, you can change the size, but that would not give you the desired result if you need the image to be background for some other content (and it will not repeat itself like you seems to want)...

## CSS3 <sub><sup>unleash the powers</sup></sub>

This is possible to do in CSS3 with `background-size`.

All modern browsers support this, so unless you need to support old browsers, this is the way to do it.
<sub>**Supported browsers:**</sub>

<sup>Mozilla Firefox 4.0+ (Gecko 2.0+), Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0+, Opera 10.0+, Safari 4.1+ (webkit 532) and Chrome 3.0+.</sup>

```css
.stretch{
/* Will stretch to specified width/height */
  background-size: 200px 150px;
}
.stretch-content{
/* Will stretch to width/height of element */
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.resize-width{
/* width: 150px, height: auto to retain aspect ratio */
  background-size: 150px Auto;
}
.resize-height{
/* height: 150px, width: auto to retain aspect ratio */
  background-size: Auto 150px;
}
.resize-fill-and-clip{ 
  /* Resize to fill and retain aspect ratio.
     Will cause clipping if aspect ratio of box is different from image. */ 
  background-size: cover;
}
.resize-best-fit{
/* Resize to best fit and retain aspect ratio.
   Will cause gap if aspect ratio of box is different from image. */ 
  background-size: contain;
}
```

In particular, I like the `cover` and `contain` values that gives us new power of control that we didn't have before.

### Round

You can also use `background-size: round` that have a meaning in combination with repeat:

```css
.resize-best-fit-in-repeat{
/* Resize to best fit in a whole number of times in x-direction */ 
  background-size: round auto; /* Height: auto is to keep aspect ratio */
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

This will adjust the image width so it fits a whole number of times in the background positioning area.

---

*Additional note*
If the size you need is static pixel size, it is still smart to physically resize the actual image. This is both to improve quality of the resize (given that your image software does a better job than the browsers), and to save bandwidth if the original image is larger than what to display.

Comment: Note that there is also the question of retina displays on iPad and iPhone and probably other high-resolution devices to come. This means it may be worth resizing larger images using CSS, and using multiple CSS files and other tricks to serve specific images. Nice intro to it here: http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/03/what-the-new-ipads-retina-display-means-for-web-developers/

Comment: This is the worst solution for now, as not every e-commerce shop is going to re-size the image as suggested. In 2009, it most likely was close to the best option, now just use the size attributes like below.

Answer (score 330):

Only CSS 3 supports that,

```
background-size: 200px 50px;
```

But I would edit the image itself, so that the user needs to load less, and it might look better than a shrunken image without antialiasing.

Comment: Unfortunately, people still use ie8

Comment: 2013 ending, still need to add `background: url('resized_image.png')\9;` for IE lt 9

Comment: This is the way to go even in 2017!

Comment: I also came from 2017 and this is how we do it.

Answer (score 23):

If your users use only Opera 9.5+, Safari 3+, Internet Explorer 9+ and Firefox 3.6+ then the answer is yes. Otherwise, no.

The [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size) property is part of CSS 3, but it won't work on most browsers.

For your purposes just make the actual image larger.

Comment: background-size: 100%; background-position:center; - this works in IE6 running on my Virtual Machine on XP Home.

Comment: IE 6,7,8 is not 'most browsers'.

Comment: Even in 2013 - while the comment "IE6,7,8 is not 'most browsers'" might be partly true in regards to IE6; IE7 and IE8 still have quite a commanding market share unfortunately. The best way I've found to do this is to use Javascript in combination with modernizr (or other means of tagging 'OLDIE').

Answer (score 19):

**Not possible**. The background will always be as large as it can be, but you can stop it from repeating itself with [`background-repeat`](http://www.eskimo.com/~bloo/indexdot/css/properties/colorbg/bgrepeat.htm).

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Secondly, the background does not go into margin-area of a box, so if you want to have the background only be on the actual contents of a box, you can use margin instead of padding.

Thirdly, you can control where the background image starts. By default it's the top left corner of a box, but you can control that with [`background-position`](http://www.eskimo.com/~bloo/indexdot/css/properties/colorbg/bgposit.htm), like this:

```
background-position: center top;
```

or perhaps

```
background-position: 20px -14px;
```

Negative positioning is used a lot with [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Comment: No, it not as large as i can be. It's always the same size, but I need to do it bigger.

Comment: Well, that's not possible. There might be options for doing that in future versions of CSS, but that's a long way off.

Comment: This answer is wrong. CSS3 has the background-size property which is supported in IE9+.

Comment: Take a look at the time stamp. In 2009, background-size was but a twinkle in WebKit's eyes. Feel free to update it, if you want, but there's already plenty other answers describing background-size.

Answer (score 12):

#### Not too hard, if you're not afraid of going a little more in depth :)

There's one *forgotten* argument:

```
background-size: contain;
```

This won't stretch your `background-image` as it would do with `cover`. It would stretch until the longer side reaches the width or height of the outer container and therefore preserving the image.

Edit: There's also `-webkit-background-size` and `-moz-background-size`.

> The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+.

[<sup>- Source: W3 Schools</sup>](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Answer (score 3):

background-size: 200px 50px
change it to 100% 100% and it will scale on the needs of the content tag like ul li or div... tried it

Answer (score 3):

In support of the answer that @tetra gave, I want to point out that if the image is an SVG, then resizing the actual image is not necessary.

Since an SVG file is just XML you can specify whatever size you want it to appear within the XML.

However, if you are using the same SVG image in different places and need it to be different sizes, then using `background-size` is very helpful.  SVG files are inherently smaller than raster images anyway and resizing on the fly with CSS can be very helpful without any performance cost that I am aware of, and certainly little to no loss of quality.

Here is a quick example:

```
<div class="hasBackgroundImage">content</div>

.hasBackgroundImage
{
    background: transparent url('/image/background.svg') no-repeat 10px 5px;
    background-size: 1.4em;
}
```

(Note: this works for me in OS X 10.7 with Firefox 8, Safari 5.1, and Chrome 16.0.912.63)

Answer (score 3):

You totally can with CSS3:

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/bg-body.png); 
    background-size: 100%; /* size the background image at 100% like any responsive img tag */
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

This will size a background image to 100% of the width of the body element and will then re-size the background accordingly as the body element re-sizes for smaller resolutions.

Here is the example: http://www.sccc.premiumdw.com/examples/resize-background-images-with-css/

Answer (score 2):

Just have nested divs to be cross browser compatible

```
   
      <div>
         <div style="background: url('bg.gif') top repeat-y;min-width:490px;">
            Put content here
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `<div>` elements:

- One is a container (it is the one which you originally wanted the
  background image to appear at).
- The second one is contained within. You set its size to the size of
  the background image (or the size you wish to be appearing).

The contained div is then set to be positioned `absolute`. This way it does not interfere with the normal flow of items in the containing div.

It enables you to use sprite images efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

```
put the below code in the body of you css file

background-image: URL('../images/wave-green-plain-colour.jpg') ;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
width:100px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the size of your background image with the current version of CSS (2.1).

You can only set: `position`, `fix`, `image-url`, `repeat-mode`, and `color`.

Answer (score 1):

You have written

```
background: url('bg.gif') top repeat-y;    
background-size: 490px;
```

but you will only see the background depending on the size of the container.

if you have an empty container with the background url and whatever the background-size is, you will not see the bg.gif.

If you set the size of the continer to

```
background: url('bg.gif') top repeat-y;    
background-size: 490px;
height: 490px;
width: 490px;
```

combined to the code you wrote above, you will be able to see the bg.gif file.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size` is working in Chrome 4.1, but so far I couldn't make it work in Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I use background images for buttons, but it only shows the image the same size as the text, even if I set width and height. Instead, I pad out my text with `&nbsp;` characters (non-breaking spaces). I slap in as many as needed, basically, until all the button background appears. So I might have code like this:

In the style sheet:

```
#v2menu-home {
    background-image:url(../v2-siteimages/button.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

In the HTML document:

```
<div id="v2menu">
    <a id="v2menu-home" href="/index.php">home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
</div><!-- v2menu -->
```

Comment: Another way is to set the size of the link to the size of the background image. In the style sheet, (under #v2menu-home in the example above) use display:block and set the height and the width there. That actually works. No need for non-breaking space characters then.

Answer (score 0):

For example:
 
Background image will always fit to container size (width 100% and height 100px).
Cross-browser CSS:

```
.app-header {
background: url("themes/default/images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100px;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100px;
-o-background-size: 100% 100px;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src = "themes/default/images/background.jpg", sizingMethod = 'scale');
background-size: 100% 100px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do in CSS3 with background-size

```
.backgroungImage {
    background: url('../imageS/background.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `background-size` in the same `background` property you can use use:

```
background:url(my-bg.png) no-repeat top center / 50px 50px;
```

Comment: I can't test, but probably.

Comment: I thought ipads didnt recognize shorthand background @orlando-leite