# Transform a background image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a CSS class defined like so:

```
.MyClass .MyIcon {
  background: url("../Images/my_icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent !important;  
}
```

But the image is a little too big for what I need. Is there a way to shrink this image from its current size of 20 x 20 to 16 x 16, **using CSS**. So just making another image is not an option.

I've been searching different sites, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Thx for any help! :D

Comment: Wow... 4 answers in 3 mins. Nice! Well, good to know that I don't have to bang my head on the wall any longer.

Comment: Please see my updated answer on how to serve a resized background image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the size of a background image just yet, only in browsers that support css3 you can use the `background-size` property.

Answer (score 1):

Only in CSS 3. It's called [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article with a good explanation: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/
Although it technically isn't the background image, it eliminates javascript and the need for css3

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered before.

[Set size on background image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-backgroundimage-with-css)

> If you need to make the image bigger,
>   you must edit the image itself in an
>   image editor.
>
> If you use the img tag, you can change
>   the size, but that would not give you
>   the desired result if you need the
>   image to be background for some other
>   content (and it will not repeat itself
>   like you seems to want)...

That being said, you could probably create a PHP Page, or something similar, to serve the image at a resized dimension.

```
.yourDivClass{
    background:url(/getImage.php?w=16&h=16&image=my_icon.png);
}
```

**getImage.php**

```
<?php
$filename="../images/".$_REQUEST['image'];
smart_resize_imageFile(
    $filename, 
    $_REQUEST['w'], 
    $_REQUEST['h'], 
    true, 
    'browser', 
    false
);


function smart_resize_imageFile( $file, $width = 0, $height = 0, $proportional = false, $output = 'file', $delete_original = true, $use_linux_commands = false){
    if ( $height <= 0 && $width <= 0 ) {
      return false;
    }

    $info = getimagesize($file);
    $image = '';

    $final_width = 0;
    $final_height = 0;
    list($width_old, $height_old) = $info;

    if ($proportional) {
      if ($width == 0) $factor = $height/$height_old;
      elseif ($height == 0) $factor = $width/$width_old;
      else $factor = min ( $width / $width_old, $height / $height_old);   

      $final_width = round ($width_old * $factor);
      $final_height = round ($height_old * $factor);

    }
    else {
      $final_width = ( $width <= 0 ) ? $width_old : $width;
      $final_height = ( $height <= 0 ) ? $height_old : $height;
    }

    switch ( $info[2] ) {
      case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
      break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
      break;
      case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
      break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

    if ( $info[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF )
        $image_resized = imagecreate( $final_width, $final_height );
    else
        $image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor( $final_width, $final_height );

    if ( ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) ) {
      $trnprt_indx = imagecolortransparent($image);

      // If we have a specific transparent color
      if ($trnprt_indx >= 0) {

        // Get the original image's transparent color's RGB values
        $trnprt_color    = imagecolorsforindex($image, $trnprt_indx);

        // Allocate the same color in the new image resource
        $trnprt_indx    = imagecolorallocate($image_resized, $trnprt_color['red'], $trnprt_color['green'], $trnprt_color['blue']);

        // Completely fill the background of the new image with allocated color.
        imagefill($image_resized, 0, 0, $trnprt_indx);

        // Set the background color for new image to transparent
        imagecolortransparent($image_resized, $trnprt_indx);


      } 
      // Always make a transparent background color for PNGs that don't have one allocated already
      elseif ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

        // Turn off transparency blending (temporarily)
        imagealphablending($image_resized, false);

        // Create a new transparent color for image
        $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_resized, 0, 0, 0, 127);

        // Completely fill the background of the new image with allocated color.
        imagefill($image_resized, 0, 0, $color);

        // Restore transparency blending
        imagesavealpha($image_resized, true);
      }
    }

    imagecopyresampled($image_resized, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $final_width, $final_height, $width_old, $height_old);
    if ( $delete_original ) {
      if ( $use_linux_commands )
        exec('rm '.$file);
      else
        @unlink($file);
    }

    switch ( strtolower($output) ) {
      case 'browser':
        $mime = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);
        header("Content-type: $mime");
        $output = NULL;
      break;
      case 'file':
        $output = $file;
      break;
      case 'return':
        return $image_resized;
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }

    switch ( $info[2] ) {
      case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        imagegif($image_resized, $output);
      break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        imagejpeg($image_resized, $output);
      break;
      case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        imagepng($image_resized, $output);
      break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not sound like what you were looking for..

But I once ended up using `<img />` tags and changed the `height` and `width` attributes as desired.