# Resize background Image in my div

Tags: html, css, background-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set size on background image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css)

I need to find a solution on how to get the same effect of the background image i have achieved [here](http://tommywebdesigner.com/Contacto.html) but using the image tag. In other words i probably need to use Javascript to do that, but i am not finding any solution suitable.

Here the Html of my body in the example page.

```
     <div id="contacto">

       <div class="home">

       </div>     

  </div>
```

The CSS is the following:

```
  #contacto {
  background-image: url("../img/barcelona-buildings.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center 965px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0 #888888 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0 #888888 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow:  2px 1px 6px 0 #888888 inset;
}


.home {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Right now  but i want to delete `background-image: url("../img/barcelona-buildings.jpg");` in the CSS and using  `<img src="../img/barcelona-buildings.jpg" alt="">` inside the `div class="home"` with Javascript automatically resize the img regarding width of the display

Is it possible? How can i achieve it?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to get rid of the CSS `background-image` property and use an `<img>` tag -- do you need to render a different image chosen dynamically? In this case, you could generate the `style` attribute of the div dynamically?

Comment: No actually no, i am asked to do that using javascript... Is that possible? how would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **IMG** write like this:

```
.home img{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: like that, the image goes over the content displayed below

Comment: give higher z-index to your content

Comment: for example write like this .content{position:relative;z-index:5}

Comment: .content, where is it? add as class of the image?