# How to force image to be within mentioned width and height?

Tags: html, css

I want some css to get the image within mentioned width and height without cropping.

I have done it like this :

```
.btnEdit{ background-image: url(/images/btn_Edit_PICO.gif); 
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 22px ; 
    width: 54px;}
```

But, it's not happening. Another button is there but with different size.

```
.btnDelete{background-image: url(/images/btn_Delete_PICO.gif); 
cursor:pointer; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: transparent; 
height: 22px ;
width: 54px;}
```

I want those to be of same size although there actual image size may differ.

Image:
[image: Edit Delete Demo]

Comment: post your working code/demo. (HTML & CSS)

Comment: I have already posted the code. I am posting the image describing it.

Comment: use percentage instead of pixels

Comment: It's not happening @RachelGallen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/KP4bh/

Comment: @Joonas Thanks man. But how to deal with background-image?

Comment: There is css3 method ( `background-size` ), but css3 is not the tool of choice _if you wish to support older browsers_. Here's a SO question/answer that should answer your question in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css/1341462#1341462

Answer (score 0):

If you have to resize the background, I don't think it can be done. If your image has the right width and height use background-position to 'crop'.

Comment: Actually, yes. I do want to resize it. I want to give width and height and I want the image to be fitted there.

Comment: There's no background resizing in CSS. What if you'd put an image-tag in the div and used overflow-hidden?

Comment: Actually, I can't in fact I don't want to use div.

Answer (score 0):

why r u using two class? if your both button are same so use only one class

CSS

```
    .btn
    { 
    background:blue; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 22px ; 
width: 54px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="btn">
<input type="Button" value="EDIT"/>
</div>

<div class="btn">
<input type="Button" value="Delete"/>
</div>
```

Comment: There's image involved and also other concerns. That's why I used two different classes. Can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the CSS3 property `background-size`?

```
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```