# How can I make icon small when using bootstrap?

Tags: css

If I want to minimize icon size, how can I make icon small when using bootstrap?

This is demo http://jsfiddle.net/AqUBu/

I'd like to minimize the size of this human icon.

[image]

```
<span class='badge badge-success'><i class='icon-user icon-white'></i><i class='icon-user icon-white'></i><i class='icon-user icon-white'></i></span>
```

Comment: post your related CSS here.

Comment: @Pawan Thanks I use bootstrap. it's way too long so that I had to use JSFiddle to put them all. Please check my demo

Comment: consider awe's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1341462/1135581

Comment: I tried them to wrap with `background-size: 50% 50%;` but it didn't work:(

Answer (score 36):

If you are using Bootstrap 3, you can use the `<small>` tag, like this: `<small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></small>`
It works perfectly with Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 24):

Glyphicons and other icons can be re-sized ***precisely*** with the CSS property `font-size:`

You know... being glyphs and all.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `class="btn btn-xs"`

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: these are no btn-xs styles in bootstrap doc, as well as `class="btn btn-xs"` doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

From http://getbootstrap.com/css/#small-text

> **Small text**
>
> For de-emphasizing inline or blocks of text, use the
>   `<small>` tag to set text at 85% the size of the parent. Heading
>   elements receive their own `font-size` for nested `<small>` elements.
>
> You may alternatively use an inline element with `.small` in place of
>   any `<small>`.

Try:

```
<span class='badge badge-success small'>
  <i class='icon-user icon-white'></i>
  <i class='icon-user icon-white'></i>
  <i class='icon-user icon-white'></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me, I am using a combination of Bootstrap 4 and FontAwesome icons. I discovered Bootstrap 4 has it's own class to make smaller buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary ">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</button>
```

[Bootstrap 4 button documentation (#Sizes)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#sizes)

If you want to make a button any smaller than this you will probably have to make some custom css, as simply changing the icon's size will no longer modify the size of the wrapping button.