# How to make image looks smaller in size that is taken from any image-sprite not a single image?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

i have one image sprite and i want certain portion of it to looks smaller in size using css??
Have you got any suggestions..???
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: The idea of sprite is to capture the image based on its position. You might have to create 2 sprite images for your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way using CSS2. However, using CSS3 you can do it using *backgound-size* property, in case your sprite is set as background of an element.

See examples of how to do this in this question: [set size on background image with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css)

Comment: Yes background-size should work fine in your case, Try something like background-size: 100px auto;  Change 100px to your desidred width of the image.