# Can I re-size background image?

Tags: html, css

Is there any idea to re-size its background image?

```
div{background: url("image.jpg") no-repeat;} 
/* here original image is  20px X 20px
and I would like to re-size its background image as 50px X 50px */
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `background-size` property but this is css3 and will only work in newer browsers

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Comment: at least which version of IE?

Comment: @Chapurlink it works in [**IE9+ browsers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ,

```
 -moz-background-size:
 -webkit-background-size:
  background-size:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-size in CSS3 or in CSS2 you can use phpthumb

```
div{background: url("phpThumb.php?src=images/image.jpg&amp;w=20&amp;h=20") no-repeat;}
```

check this site if you are interesed in php solution

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php