# How to control the image resolution painted as the background for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to paint an image as the background for a div element. But not able to figure out on how to control the resolution of the image.

My image resolution is 1400X900 px. I wanted to paint that image so that it wont be trimmed and fits to the screen. How to set the image size so that it will be fitted to screen? I tried using background-size but it is not working in I.E.

below is my div element

```
<div style="background:url('...');">
    some more elements
</div>
```

Comment: If `background-size` is not working in IE then we need to know the version number (IE 8 does not support that) and see all the code you are trying to use. Also, I think [this is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css).

Answer (score 0):

`background-size` (`background-size: contain` for instance) is the way to go. However, as you yourself note, this doesn't work in IE 8 and below.

For old IEs you can consider using [background-size polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill), which emulates `background-size`.

You could write a script that does the same thing but that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Css3` option `background-size`.

For example
    `background-size:100% 100%;`