# CSS printing fix of `background-size: cover;`

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Is there a cross-browser fix for enabling `background-image` in combination with `background-size: cover;` when printing a webpage?

I would appreciate all kinds of solutions even those using JavaScript!

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css

Comment: @Waffles My question is about using CSS while printing.

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

Add meta-tag on your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

In the print.css next tag:

```
#mydiv {background-image: url('link/to/imagefile'); background-size:cover; display:block;}
```

In the style.css (on screen):

```
 #mydiv {display:none}
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the problem is. Basically it is not possible to use the `background-image` property for printing media. However there are workarounds using html `img` tags and some styling. I am just hoping there is a workaround for the `background-size` property too.

Comment: @Tim: do you have a jsfiddle link with your issue?

Comment: @Tim: did you refered to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Ux4K6/3/
It's solved only with css

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the `background-size: cover;` does not seem to be working. Try it with a larger resolution to see what I mean.