# How to scale down CSS background-image when using various background-positions?

Tags: html, css, image

I use three shots of a button on an image to give impression of a button in action.

**Normal / Hover / Active**.

Here is an image of that:

[image]

The CSS code for picking the right image for the right state is here:

```
#btnSet1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
}
.btn1 a {
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.btn1 a.link1 p {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    left: -10px;
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111;
    opacity: 1;
}
.btn1 a.link1:link {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 144px;
    background: url(../images/btn3.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.btn1 a.link1:hover {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 144px;
    background: url(../images/btn3.png) no-repeat 0px -90px;
}
.btn1 a.link1:active {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 144px;
    background: url(../images/btn3.png) no-repeat 0px -180px;
}
.btn1 a.link1:visited {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 144px;
    background: url(../images/btn3.png) no-repeat 0px -270px;
}
#tHeader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 300px;
}
```

I made these images to be large, because I need to scale them, occasionally.  The HTML image element can be used to stretch any image, but I only show a region of the total image with the CSS style.  So, for the sake of clarity, let's call each button face being shown a view... so, how can I stretch the view of each button face in code, since the x y refer to unscaled metrics of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**background-size**

sprite *

**px**

**css**

```
div{
 width:75px;height:45px;
 background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yNbR.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
 background-size:75px 135px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:45px;
}
div:hover{
 background-position:0px -45px;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/katPx/

---

**percent**

**css**

```
div{
 width:75px;height:45px;
 background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yNbR.png) no-repeat 0% 0%;
 background-size:100% auto;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:45px;
}
div:hover{
 background-position:0% 50%;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/katPx/1/

- this last one scales automatically based on the container size.

use a class

```
.btns{
 width:75px;height:45px;
 background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yNbR.png) no-repeat 0% 0%;
 background-size:100% auto;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:45px;
}
.btns:hover{
 background-position:0% 50%;
}
```

html

```
<div class="btns">whatever</div>
```

**demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/katPx/2/

Comment: Thank you for the alternative idea of using a div and a viewPort.   Brilliant idea...

Comment: i like div's cause you need to add more css to show a anchor properly.

Comment: You are inspired today...  Thanks for the other two examples...  Both very useful...

Answer (score 1):

How about using CSS background-size?

```
.btn1 a.link1:link {
    background-size: 144px 90px;
}
```

This post has more info - [Set size on background image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It works fine.  I just have to scale the fonts and it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using percentage-based `background-size` and `background-position`. Here is a basic working example you can adapt to your needs.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHztM/1/)

```
a {
    display: block;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yNbR.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a:hover {
    background-position: 0 50%;
}
a:active {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
a.big {
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
}
a.small {
    width: 75px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Nice reuse of code... concise and efficient... Excellent.