# Browser Zoom at 100%, not showing actual image pixel ratio

Tags: html, css, browser, zooming

I'm new to web development and I'm facing a frustrating issue, I've set an background image of size 1920px x 1044px, but when the browser zoom (Firefox) is set to 100% the image is much bigger than its actual size, I have to zoom the browser to 80% to see the website accurately. It's the same with the rest of the content. Is there something specific to understand? The issue is relatively the same with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make your images layout to be 100% width and 100% height,
you can add this to your main.css file:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
```

btw,
there was a similar discussion about background image size:
[Set size on background image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking but if I understand igt right you should in css set the width to 100%

So this is what the html should look like

```
<img src="imagehere" id="imageid"/>
```

And then the css

```
#imageid{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I hope that helps! Littleswany!