# Very weird behavior when working with background size CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, background-size

I recently learned about the `background-size` property thanks to this topic

[Set size on background image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css)

As you can guess, I am trying to make a background image take up the full screen and no more/no less. Here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/1x7ytdaa/

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.crystalinks.com/ColosseumNight2.jpg')";
document.body.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
```

Here is what the `contain` property does

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

It shouldn't matter what size the image is. If it's smaller, it should be scaled to the full size of the screen. If it's larger, it should be scaled down.

In the fiddle, you can see that the image is repeated 5 times horizontally and 5 1/2 times vertically.

I've tried `100% 100%` and while the width stretches the full screen, it still shows the same image 5 1/2 times vertically

I can not explain this behavior. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try adding `background-repeat: no-repeat`?

Comment: Yes that seemed to be most of the issue. Also needed to set the width and height of the body to 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- background-repeat
- width and height of body

As you can in [an edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x7ytdaa/1/), the problem is that the default value of `background-repeat` is `repeat`. Therefore, the image will be repeated rather than stretched. That doesn't solve everything, though, as the body and HTML elements should have a width defined that is 100%.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.crystalinks.com/ColosseumNight2.jpg')";
document.body.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```

If you want to cover the whole screen, use `cover` instead of contain. Cover makes sure that the element is completely covered, whereas contain simply makes sure that the background image is maximally contained (which can cause white space).

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
position: fixed;
background-position: center;
overflow-x: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(img/xxx.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
overflow-y: scroll;
```