# Controlling the size of a background image

Tags: html, css

With JavaScript, the element is assigned to `var a`.  If I simply assign its style background to an image (most images) as such: `a.style = 'background:url(image.jpg)';`, the image's width and length will adjust perfectly to fit that of the div element's by default.

One particular issue though:  I've snapped a quick pic with my phone (.jpg) and downloaded it on my pc and assigned its url value to the div element's background. It however does not adjust its width and height to that of the div element's.

Why is this? and how do I correct this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there isn't enough information to know what might be affecting your element.  It is possible for multiple CSS rules to apply to an element, and any of these CSS rules could cause the symptoms you are seeing.  On that note, this isn't really a JavaScript question, it's an HTML/CSS question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set size on background image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css)

Comment: use `background-size:100% 100%`

Answer (score 0):

To control the size of the background-image, you can use the background-size property.

To ensure the image stays within the constraints of the div, you would use "contain"

```
background-size: contain;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: while it fits in the div, it repeats a portion of it

Comment: in response to that I've edited the background property as such: `a.style = background:url("image.jpg") no-repeat';`, and as a result, the said repeated portion is now white space.